# Use of って when quotation doesn't make sense

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-って

I'm playing through a game right now and I'm seeing って used at the end of sentences a lot. I know って can be a shorthand version of the と particle, but it doesn't make sense as nobody is being quoted or nothing is is being declared as in "X is called this"

For example a character says

> うわっ！　ホントにおかしいって！
>
> My translation: Uwaa! This is really strange!

After a friend screams for suddenly being really hungry

The use of the って doesn't make sense here to me, so what is really intended or why is this ending used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This type of って is mainly used to repeat one's opinion, like "I'm saying ～" or "I told you, ～". So it's still quotative in a sense; the speaker is quoting their own previous statement. For example, depending on the context, 「寝ろって。」 can mean either "[Someone] told you to sleep" (quote from a third speaker) or "I told you, go to bed!"

But って is also often used when you say something for the first time, and in such cases it's just like "come on", "you know", or "I tell you", which are used to strongly seek agreement.

> 気にするな**って**、大丈夫だ**って**!
> Never mind, it'll be okay!

> なあ、この屋敷はヤバい**って**…。
> Hey, this mansion is crazy, I tell you.

Comment: We actually do this in (US?) English too. "Hey, this mansion is crazy I tell you".

Comment: @user3856370 Thank you, I incorporated that

Comment: Is this similar to よas a sentence-terminating particle?

Comment: @Upper_Case Yes, very similar.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! @user3856370's example is actually really great. Their example is almost exactly how I first made sense of everything when I originally read the answer. I'm in the US and I would definitely say something like "I'm telling you its crazy!"