# って to mean "I said" rather than "I heard"

Tags: word-choice

```
大丈夫って
```

can either mean "I heard someone said it's ok" or it can mean "I said it's ok"

How do I know which one is being implied if someone says that to me?

Comment: Can you give a context where "I said it's ok" and "I heard someone said it's ok" could be confused? I'm struggling to think of one.

Comment: For example Me: Sorry for being late . 相手:　大丈夫じゃないって. From my perspective, it can mean "I said its not ok" or "you already told me it's not ok" perhaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *usually* tell the difference from the pitch/intonation, but not always, and you would have to tell from the context. For example:

> 意味[ないって]{HLLL}。 -- "I'm telling you~~!" (but could also mean "S/he told me~~")
> 意味[ないって]{HLLH}。 -- "S/he told me~~"

> 大丈夫[だって]{LLL}。 -- "I'm telling you~~" (but could also mean "S/he told me~~")
> 大丈夫[だって]{LLH}。 -- "S/he told me~~"
> 大丈夫[だって]{HHL}！ -- "I'm telling you~~!" (more emphatic)

> [ヤバいって]{LHLLL}... -- "I'm telling you..."
> [ヤバいって]{LHLLH}。 -- "S/he told me~~"

Examples taken from related threads:

- [Use of って when quotation doesn't make sense](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69376/9831)
- [Some questions about って](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18737/9831)

And your example:

> 大丈夫[って]{LL}。 -- *usually* means "I'm telling you~~!"
> 大丈夫[って]{LH}。 -- "S/he told me~~"