# って used at the end of the sentence, without implicating hearsay nor quoting

Tags: particles, particle-って

I very often see って at the end of a sentence in anime/visual novels, but sometimes, it doesn't convey the idea of hearsay nor is it quoting someone.

I just came by this dialogue in death note, the situation is that criminals in prison have been dying from heart attacks for an unknown reason, and people are chatting about the phenomenon.
Two random people are talking to each other

> Guy 1: やっぱ警察がやってんのかな？
> Guy 2: 警察にそんな力ない**って**

Here, to me personally, the って sounds like as if it's added for emphasis, like with ってば, as in "C'mon, the police doesn't have the power to do that (I am telling you)" but less aggressive then ってば.

Perhaps maybe it could also be a って思う, but the second guy replied with such on oblivious tone, and falling intonation, that I don't think he was just expressing his opinion, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18738/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/69378/9831

Comment: Ah, yes it does, thank you very much!